# How to use re with beautifulsoup in python 2.7 to suppress certain results?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use beautifulsoup and re to grab a list of URLs, but I want to suppress one of the results and I can't figure out how to do so.

This code gets me 29 (of 35) URLs:

```
issue_index = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('past'))
```

That's one too many.

One of the URLs has `target="_blank"`, and I would like to exclude this URL from the others.

However, I can't figure out how to do it.

This does the exact opposite of what I want, returning only the URL I want to discard.

```
issue_index = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('past'), target="_blank")
```

This code removes the bad URL (with the target attribute), but it doesn't filter the list with the regular expression.

```
def remove(a):
    return a.has_attr('href') and not a.has_attr('target')

issue_index = soup.find_all(remove)
```

It's so maddening.

Comment: really, a downvote with no clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest, most straight-forward approach is to filter out unwanted tags after `find_all`:

```
issue_index = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('past'))
issue_index = filter(lambda tag: tag.attrs.get('target') != '_blank', issue_index)
for tag in issue_index:
    print(tag)
```

The second approach is to replace the simple first parameter (`'a'`) with a filter function:

```
def a_not_blank(tag):
    return tag.name == 'a' and tag.attrs.get('target') != '_blank'

issue_index = soup.find_all(a_not_blank, href=re.compile('past'))
for tag in issue_index:
    print(tag)
```

The third approach is to go all out and use a single filter function:

```
def myfilter(tag):
    pattern = re.compile('past')
    return tag.name == 'a' \
            and tag.has_attr('href') \
            and re.match(pattern, tag.attrs['href']) \
            and tag.attrs.get('target') != '_blank'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for tag in soup.find_all(myfilter):
    print(tag)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a helpful answer! I was combing the docs and not coming up with anything. I am using the first approach, but those functions are great to study.